# Multiple drop down questions selection in angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.questions = ["Select a question from the following options.", "What is your favorite color?", "What is your favorite sport?","What is your favorite car?","What is your first pet name?","What is your first car color?"];

   });

</script>
<body>

<div  ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-3 control-label" id="consumerChoice">Consumer's Choices</label>
                
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in questions" class="form-control">
                    </select>
                            </div> <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Answer">
                </div></div>
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in questions" class="form-control">
                    </select>
                            </div> <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Answer">
                </div></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in questions" class="form-control">
                    </select>
                            </div> <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Answer">
          </div></div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm developing multiple security questions in the dropdown and its answers using angular js. The problem is that these questions come from an array inside the controller and on clicking on drop down, all the other dropdowns are also changing and first selected option should not be displayed in the other drop downs.I need to avoid it.I don't know where I'm making the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ng-model should be different for each select**:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.questions = ["Select a question from the following options.", "What is your favorite color?", "What is your favorite sport?", "What is your favorite car?", "What is your first pet name?", "What is your first car color?"];
  $scope.model = {};

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-3 control-label" id="consumerChoice">Consumer's Choices</label>

      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <select ng-model="selectedName1" class="form-control">
            <option value="{{x}}" ng-repeat="x in questions track by $index">{{x}} </option>
                    </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Answer">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <select ng-model="selectedName2" class="form-control">
              <option ng-if="selectedName1 != x" value="{{x}}" ng-repeat="x in questions track by $index">{{x}}  </option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Answer">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <select ng-model="selectedName3" class="form-control">
              <option value="{{x}}" ng-if="selectedName1 != x && selectedName2 != x" ng-repeat="x in questions track by $index">{{x}} </option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Answer">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But when you already chose the first option in the first drop down,it shouldn't be showing in the second dropdown right?

Comment: you have to implement the logic for it.it will not automatically remove the option from second dropdown.

Comment: Thanks,Updated the question.

Comment: @HemaNandagopal updated the answer according to your requirement.

Comment: Great.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

please set different names for different select tags

You cannot use same model for different select tags.